# Discord.NET SlashCommand Make Parameter/Argument Nullable

Tags: c#, .net, discord

I want to make one or more arguments passed into to the slash command nullable (not optional), here's the small example:

```cs
[SlashCommand("licenseaddaddress", "Adds an address to a license")]
public async Task ExecuteAsync(
    [Summary("LicenseKey", "The license key")]
    string licenseKey,
    [Summary("Address", "The address be added")]
    string address,
    [NotOptionalArgument] string? info) // Looking for similar behavior of NotOptionalArgument or marking the argument with `?` (can be null)
{
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the parameter a default value? For example `string info = ""`

Comment: No, I haven't tried but just tried and the problem is still the same, however if I try to remove the argument from the input field (in discord) it says: `This option is required. Specify a value.`

Comment: So, that means argument can be made not optional somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_framework/intro.html#optional-parameters) for Discord.Net:

> Parameters with default values (ie. `int count = 0`) will be displayed as optional parameters on Discord Client.

So you need to change your method to look like this:

```
[SlashCommand("licenseaddaddress", "Adds an address to a license")]
public async Task ExecuteAsync(
    [Summary("LicenseKey", "The license key")]
    string licenseKey,
    [Summary("Address", "The address be added")]
    string address,
    string? info = null) // <-- include a default value, null works here too
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This will now show the command in Discord like this:

[image]